# Требуется ли освобождение памяти в данном случае(Objective-C)?

Tags: xcode, objective-c, утечка-памяти, memory

Пишу свою библиотеку по структурам данных.

Узел дерева у меня хранит NSMutableArray узлов детей, в случае, когда я хочу заменить всех детей я просто передаю новый NSMutableArray с новыми детьми.

Должен ли я как-то освобождать память старого массива с узлами?

TreeNode.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TreeNode : NSObject
{
  id data;
  TreeNode *parent;
  NSMutableArray *children;
}

@property (nonatomic) id data;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) TreeNode *parent;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSMutableArray *children;

- (void) addChild: (TreeNode*) Child;
- (void) addChildren: (NSMutableArray*) Children;
- (void) addParent: (TreeNode*) Parent;

@end
```

TreeNode.m

```
#import "TreeNode.h"

@implementation TreeNode

//Свойства
@synthesize data;
@synthesize parent;
@synthesize children;

//Методы
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        data = nil;
        parent = nil;
        children = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}
- (id) initWithData: (id) Data
             Parent: (TreeNode*) Parent
           Children: (NSMutableArray*) Children {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        self.data = Data;
        self.parent = Parent;
        self.children = Children;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void) addChild: (TreeNode*) Child {
    if(children == nil) {
        children = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    [children addObject:Child];
    Child.parent = self;
}
- (void) addChildren: (NSMutableArray*) Children {

}
- (void) addParent: (TreeNode*) Parent {
    self.parent = Parent;
    [Parent addChild: self];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не должны, для свойст сеттеры-гетеры делаются автоматом на основании атрибутов и там уже есть все что нужно. Другой вопрос что вы похоже пытаетесь писать их вручную, тогда вопрос используется ли у вас ARC или нет? Вообще после его введения количество утечек стало минималным

Но вот сам по себе ваш код не рабочий:

1. вы зачем-то вручную делаете привязку свойств к иварам (хотяэто уже давно можно не делать, ну да само по себе это не ошибка) и делаете её неправильно, а именно полная запись `@synthesize data;` выглядит как `@synthesize data=_data;` т.е. ваше свойство привязывает к iVar _data, а вовсе не к объявленному вами data.
2. Вы же сами объявили свойства как только для чтения, так зачем вы в них пытаетесь писать? Компилятор выдаст вам ошибку. Если все дело в том что вы хотите дергать у Parent addChild при присвоении, то это вполне можно сделать и в сеттере написав его вручную, как именно будет выглядеть его код зависит от того используете ли вы ARC

Comment: Спасибо, что указали на ошибки. Я пишу первый день, до этого писал на С#, поэтому все понять сразу не получается.

Свойства пытался написать как в C#, т.е. у меня есть поле, а это для предоставления к нему доступа из вне только для чтения.

По поводу ARC, да, использую.